# Can't connect SFTP(AWS EC2) with QuotaGuard Static IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-ec2, quotaguard

I am using **QuotaGuard Static Addon** on Heroku to access the **SFTP server(AWS EC2)** which has whitelisted IP.

I have tried to connect with a **private key** file.
This is my code.

```
def connect
  puts "started"
  Net::SSH.start(ENV["HOST"], ENV["USER"],
    {
      :key_data => [ ENV["FTP_KEY"] ],
      :keys => [],
      :keys_only => true,
      :verbose => :debug,
      :proxy => proxy
    }
  ) do |ssh|
    ssh.sftp.connect do |sftp|
      sftp.dir.foreach("/") do |entry|
          puts entry.longname
      end
    end
  end
  puts "done"
end

def quotaguard
  URI(ENV["QUOTAGUARDSTATIC_URL"])
end

def proxy
  Net::SSH::Proxy::HTTP.new(quotaguard.host,quotaguard.port, :user => quotaguard.user,:password=> quotaguard.password)
end
```

But it is failed to connect with this error.

```
WARN: Net::SSH::Proxy::ConnectError: {:version=>"HTTP/1.1", :code=>502, :reason=>"Bad Gateway", :headers=>{}, :body=>nil}
```

**HOST**, **USER**, **FTP_KEY**, and **QUOTAGUARDSTATIC_URL** are **Heroku Env variables**.

My thought:

I think to connect **AWS EC2** using the **proxy**, maybe some settings need to be configured to allow **proxy** on **AWS EC2**.

But not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There was the wrong Security Group on AWS EC2.
I updated and I can connect now.